# Vue PWA Template, using SVG sprites

Tags: svg, webpack, vue.js

i'm currently trying to use an svg sprite within a vue component, but i can't get it to work at all. I'm googling for several hours now but can't find a working solution. I've tried adding svg-loader to the webpack config, but nothing works. All I simply wanna do is this:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="../assets/fa-regular.svg#bars"/></svg>
```

But I'm always getting a 404 for 'fa-regular.svg'. What am I missing? I don't even know where to start. Is this a vue-loader problem? Webpack problem?

Maybe someone faced a similar problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

> SVG 2 removed the need for the xlink namespace, so instead of xlink:href you should use href.

So try this:

```
<svg><use href="../assets/fa-regular.svg#bars"/></svg>
```